# How to create a web worker from an extension service worker

Tags: javascript, multithreading, google-chrome-extension, service-worker, web-worker

I will start by explaining what I am trying to achieve.

I want to create an extension that switches between tabs on different chrome windows, displaying each one for X amount of time.

I found a similar extension, but it was done using manifest V2, and it does not support multiple windows.

I wanted to implement multiple window switching by creating a web worker for every window, and have it change the active tab.

The issue is when I try to create a web worker inside the service worker using `var worker = new Worker('loop_worker.js');` it gives the error `ReferenceError: Worker is not defined`

Any way I can make a web worker from an extension? Or do you have other suggestions to achieve the desired behavior?

Comment: Not possible in ManifestV3 background script: https://crbug.com/1219164