# Saving to SQLite from Chrome Extension

Tags: sqlite, google-chrome-extension, webassembly

There is a new JSWASM approach that allows saving to SQLite (the fast OPFS way) in the browser via a javascript Worker. A sample is [here](https://github.com/randyl/sqlite3-wasm-demo-extension) that is (sort of) for a Chrome extension. Ideally, it would allow saving from the background.js, but it's unclear whether a worker can be called from there in MV3 based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73755145/how-to-create-a-web-worker-from-an-extension-service-worker) and [this](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1219164). Does anyone have a simple working example closer to my use case, which is saving content from the user's active tab to a SQLite database? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OPFS depends on the `createSyncAccessHandle()` method, which is exposed in `Worker` threads. The usual feature detection goes like this:

```js
if (self instanceof WorkerGlobalScope && 'createSyncAccessHandle' in self.FileSystemFileHandle.prototype) {
  // OPFS in `Worker` is supported!
}
```

Now an extension service worker (as currently implemented in Chrome) is an instance of `ServiceWorkerGlobalScope`, so the API is not supported there.

Unfortunately at the moment the only choice is to open an extension page and then run the OPFS code from there.

Comment: Thanks... Gosh, so out of (a) content js, (b) background js, (c) popup js, (d) separately launched page, only (d) allows accessing SQLite via OPFS? (I'm assuming there's no trick with 'c' to receive a 'please save' message). That really cuts down on the use cases. Guess I need to cache to regular storage and periodically nudge the user to open a page to save... :-(

Comment: Yes, at the moment it boils down to this. It would be interesting to investigate if the API could be made accessible from a `ServiceWorkerGlobalScope` as well. Maybe worth bringing this forward to the [WebExtensions CG](https://github.com/w3c/webextensions/issues).

Comment: Thank you. I created an issue at the site you linked to: 
https://github.com/w3c/webextensions/issues/352